# Updating the string using function in c

Tags: arrays, c, c-strings, string-literals, strcpy

I have written following c code to update the char array **rb** but it is printing garbage value

```
#include <stdio.h>
void update(char* buff){
    char word[] = "HII_O";
    buff = word;
    return;
}

int main(){
    char rb[6];
    update(rb);
    rb[5] = '\0';
    printf("[%s]\n",rb);
    return 0;
}
```

The restriction is we can't use any other library. So how to solve this

Comment: `buff = word` -> `strcpy(buf, word)`. Currently you're only modifying the local parameter.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 but that would require string.h

Comment: Making your own `strcpy` function is pretty simple. You'll just need to put a `for` loop in its place and copy `word` to `buff` character by character.

Comment: `buff[0] = word[0]; buf[1] = word[1];` etc. Do that in a loop.

Comment: @kaylum got it,

Comment: @ancadancad What's wrong with using string.h?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Nothing, this(or any other) library wasn't allowed in the question I was solving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the function `update` the parameter `buff` is a local variable of the function that will not be alive after exiting the function.

You can imagine the function call the following way

```
update( rb );
//...
void update( /*char* buff*/){
    char *buff = rb;
    char word[] = "HII_O";
    buff = word;
    return;
}
```

As you see the original array was not changed.

That is at first the pointer `buff` was initialized by the address of the first element of the source array `rb`.

```
    char *buff = rb;
```

and then this pointer was reassigned with the address of the first element of the local character array `word`

```
    buff = word;
```

What you need is to copy characters of the string literal `"HII_O"` into the source array `rb` using standard string function `strcpy` or `strncpy`.

For example

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void update(char* buff){
    strcpy( buff, "HII_O" );
}

int main(){
    char rb[6];
    update(rb);
    printf("[%s]\n",rb);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`buff` is a **local variable** to the function. It is initialized to point to the first element of the `rb` array in `main` but changes to `buff` will **not change** the `rb` array. So

```
buff = word;
```

makes `buff` point to the string literal `"HII_O"` but there is no change to the `rb` array.

The normal solution would be

```
void update(char* buff){
    strcpy(buff, "HII_O");
}
```

However, you write ...

> The restriction is we can't use any other library.

Well, in order to set a fixed value like your code does, you don't need any library function.

You don't any need other variables, string literals, etc.

Just simple character assignments like:

```
void update(char* buff){
    buff[0] = 'H';
    buff[1] = 'I';
    buff[2] = 'I';
    buff[3] = '_';
    buff[4] = 'O';
    buff[5] = '\0';
}

int main(){
    char rb[6];
    update(rb);
    printf("[%s]\n",rb);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strcpy(rb, "HII_O");`. I think here we need to use `strcpy(buff, "HII_O");`. Because `rb` is not having any scope inside this function.

Comment: @VishnuCS That was a typo. Corrected now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you cannot use any library function, just do de copying cell by cell, change

```
void update( /*char* buff*/){
    char *buff = rb;
    char word[] = "HII_O";
    buff = word;
    return;
}
```

(you cannot assign arrays as a whole in C)
into:

```
void update(char *buff) {
    char *word = "HII_O";
    int index;
    /* copy characters, one by one, until character is '\0' */
    for (index = 0; word[index] != '\0'; index = index + 1) {
        buff[index] = word[index];
    }
    /* index ended pointing to the next character, so we can
     * do the next assignment. */
    buff[index] = '\0'; /* ...and copy also the '\0' */
}
```